# Primary Identity Column of table gets random value in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, primary-key, identity-column

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Person](
[PersonID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Phone] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In this table when inserting value from application using stored procedure with query

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_PersonName]
       ([Name])
 VALUES
       ('name')
```

the 'PersonID' column got unusual value. The value jumps randomly like, from 1896 to 11896 and again jumps from 11905 to 21905. i worry if such jumps occurs the range could be insufficient and the data seems quite unorganized. I wonder if those unused value would be reused or not? After inserting some data what should i do to re managed the sequence? i am worried with the issue, this didn't happen in 2010 though i used the same pattern of code as in 2012. help me!

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Martin that actually didn't solve the problem to me but that helped to understand the problem quit more.

Comment: #barcanoj - This question is definitely an exact duplicate. You say in the comment to Rahul that trace flag 272 worked. That is mentioned in the accepted answer there. Along with a link to the Microsoft Connect thread where this behaviour change is discussed in much more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are trying to insert a new column to your primary key column.

If you have a table lets say with 1000 rows and you delete the record at 797 position. Then when you will insert a new row to your table then the value will be inserted at 1001 position not at 797.

> I wonder if those unused value would be reused or not?

No the values will not be reused. As whenever you delete a column from the table and then try to insert the value again in the table then the value will be inserted to a new position.

**EDIT:-**

Also you may find **[this](http://www.sqlserver-training.com/sequence-breaks-gap-in-numbers-after-restart-sql-server-gap-between-numbers-after-restarting-server/-)** helpful.

Microsoft added **sequences** in SQL Server 2012

> By default when you create a SEQUENCE you can either supply CACHE
>   size. Caching is used to increase performance for applications that
>   use sequence objects by minimizing the number of disk IOs that are
>   required to generate sequence numbers.

To fix this issue, you need to make sure, you add a NO CACHE option in sequence creation / properties like this.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_Sequence
    AS INT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 0
    NO MAXVALUE
   NO CACHE
```

However if you want the same old behavior then you may use **trace flag 272**

Since the trace flag 272 option worked for OP. Here are the steps to [add trace flag 272](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity):-

1. Open "SQL Server Configuration Manager"
2. Click "SQL Server Services" on the left pane
3. Right-click on your SQL Server instance name on the right pane
4. Click "Properties"
5. Click "Startup Parameters"
6. On the "specify a startup parameter" textbox type "-T272"
7. Click "Add"
8. Confirm the changes

Comment: Name is not the primary column and i have not deleted any row.

Comment: Name is not a primary key column but when you insert a new entry in the table then the primary key is automatically created

Comment: increment value is 1 so the value should have increased by 1 but in this case when i insert new data value goes from 1896 to 11896.

Comment: @barcanoj:- This may be due to the Squence which are added by Microsoft in SQL Server 2012. Updated my answer too. Hope that helps!

Comment: I have not used sequence anywhere, is there any default setting? How can i overcome the issue now after i inserted some data.

Comment: @barcanoj:- You may use trace flag 272 for the old behavior!

Comment: @barcanoj:- Also I have provided you the workaround for the same in my answer!

Comment: Thanks for the support. specifying startup parameter to "-T272" the problem seemed to be solved.